# copy *.ext *.ex_ doesn't work with absolute path's

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line-interface

I can rename all files in the current directory with a `*.ext` extension to `*.ex_` by doing this:

```
rename *.ext *.ex_
```

It doesn't seem that this works however with absolute path's. eg.

```
rename C:\path\to\*.ext C:\path\to\*.ex_
```

When I try I get the following error:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: remove the absolute path in destination, i.e. ren c:\...\\*.ext *.ex_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [`rename`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/rename.mspx?mfr=true) documentation:

```
rename [Drive:][Path] filename1 filename2
```

so, to be correct you should use rename like this:

```
rename C:\path\to\*.ext *.ex_
```

full path only for first argument

Answer (score 1):

> rename C:\path\to\*.ext *.ex_

or

> ren C:\path\to\*.ext *.ex_

and if you want to rename them to a new destination you could use xcopy

> xcopy C:\path\to\*.ext C:\path\to-new\*.ex_